# How to change 'choose an option' in magento attribute dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, attribute-set

I created an Attribute Set. I would like to know if I can change the default option list item wording in the Admin Panel's backend?  See screen shot:

[image: See screen shot]

Comment: its a attribute set or attribute (dropdown)

Comment: It's an Attribute Set @Kothari, not an attribute. Let me know if you know how to change it or if it is changeable. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting update your question with url

Comment: Please tag your questions with the Magento version you're using to avoid confusion. I did it for you this time.

Comment: Also it's preferred to upload screenshots to stackexchange instead of linking them externally to make sure they are still visible in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify `configurable.phtml` template file for this:

copy this file from here :

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options

And paste it in your theme location:

> app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Just find  `<option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?>` this code and replace it with your text.
If you want to show backed label then just replace above line from this code:

```
<option><?php echo 'Select '.$_attribute->getLabel() ?></option>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Helps a lot @Arunendra. I was hoping for something in the Admin backend, but I can handle core code mods this way -- no problem. Plus, I was hoping to be able to customize the top level option like "Choose a size..." or Choose a color..." depending on what dropdown list I was implementing.